# How synapses are hold in place if they're not phisically attached?

Tags: neuroanatomy

When two neurons connect to form a synapse, between the pre-synaptic and post-synaptic cells some space is found (synaptic cleft). How does this keep in position if there is no physical connection between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a physical connection.

Synapses are held together by adhesion molecules, like cadherins and neuroligins/neurexins.

[Missler, M., Südhof, T. C., & Biederer, T. (2012). Synaptic cell adhesion. Cold Spring Harbor perspectives in biology, 4(4), a005694.](https://cshperspectives.cshlp.org/content/4/4/a005694.short)